# Ajax search to database isn't loading results. Laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a form. In one input in the form, I'm trying to implement a dynamic typeahead feature.

The error i'm getting is

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
>   advertise-ajax?term=b&_type=query&q=b Failed to load resource:

My Route for the form itself and then the ajax is

```
Route::get('/advertise', 'AdvertisementController@index');
Route::get('/advertise-ajax', 'AdvertisementController@townload');
```

My Controllers for  the above are

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\PropertyAdvert;
use DB;
use Auth;

class AdvertisementController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
      return view('pages/Advert/create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request){
      $Advert = new PropertyAdvert();

      $Advert::create(
        [
          "photo"       => $request->photo,
          "address"     => $request->address,
          "county"      => $request->county,
          "town"        => $request->town,
          "type"        => $request->type,
          "rent"        => $request->rent,
          "date"        => $request->date,
          "bedrooms"    => $request->bedrooms,
          "bathrooms"   => $request->bathrooms,
          "furnished"   => $request->furnished,
          "description" => $request->description
        ]
      );

      return "Success. Your adveret has been published";
    }

    public function show($id){
    $Advert = PropertyAdvert::where('id', $id)->first();
    return view('pages/Advert/show', compact('Advert'));
  }

  public function townload(Request $request)
    {
        $data = [];


        if($request->has('q')){
            $search = $request->q;
            $data = DB::table("town")
                    ->select("id","name")
                    ->where('name','LIKE',"%$search%")
                    ->get();
        }


        return response()->json($data);
    }

}
```

The ajax which is in the same blade template as the form is.
This is one input in a form.

I have the towns stored in a database called town already. If a user types in dub, dublin should appear as an option for example.

```
<select class="town form-control" style="width:500px;" name="town"></select>

                        <script type="text/javascript">


      $('.town').select2({
        placeholder: 'Select an item',
        ajax: {
          url: '/advertise-ajax',
          dataType: 'json',
          delay: 250,
          processResults: function (data) {
            return {
              results:  $.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        text: item.name,
                        id: item.id
                    }
                })
            };
          },
          cache: true
        }
      });


</script>
```

Comment: question edited to include chrome console error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You get ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT because of some of your ad-blocker block
>   your request

If your URL contains words such as "**advert**", "**click**", "**ad**", "**doubleclick**" 
Then ad-blocker will block it.

you have **advertise-ajax** URL so ad-blocker think this is for ads so it's blocking your request so you can use another word for your URL

Comment: i have createadvert as a route and that works just fine

Comment: I disabled adblocker and the issue is still there

Comment: you can try with another name of URL it's working or not?

Comment: I changed it to townsearch. I'm still not getting results from the db, but that error is gone. Now this is what happens when i type -> https://imgur.com/a/SIFJE

Comment: It's working now. I forget to re seed the database after refreshing a migrate

Answer (score 0):

Wrong parameter for `where` function! which should be like this:

```
->where('name','LIKE',"%".$search."%")
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same issue. I update the question with the error provided in chrome. >Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
>advertise-ajax?term=b&_type=query&q=b Failed to load resource: